# Does it have an equivalent query in cql/cassandra for "alter table add column if column not exists"?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to add the column for table that if the column is not existed.

I ran the `Alter Table <table> add <column_name> <type>;` however, it will have this error message if the column already exists.

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid column name <column_name> because it conflicts with an existing column"
```

Does it have a way to do a similar check on whether the column exists or not?

Thank

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation of Cassandra 4.1](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/ddl.html#alter-table-statement) you can use the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause, i.e.:

```sql
ALTER TABLE addamsFamily ADD IF NOT EXISTS gravesite varchar;
```

I quote (emphasis mine):

> The ALTER TABLE statement can:
>
> ADD a new column to a table. The primary key of a table cannot ever be altered. A new column, thus, cannot be part of the primary key. Adding a column is a constant-time operation based on the amount of data in the table. If the new column already exists, the statement will return an error, **unless IF NOT EXISTS is used** in which case the operation is a no-op.
>
> [...]

For versions before 4.1, you need to use Aaron's answer based on `system_schema`.

Comment: Just a heads-up, but this only works w/ version 4.1 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

So I checked Tasos's answer, and it works with Apache Cassandra 4.1.  It **does not** work with 4.0 or any version prior to that.

If you're using an older version, you can try querying `system_schema` like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROm system_schema.columns
WHERE keyspace_name = 'nosql1' AND table_name = 'users' AND column_name='description';
```

If you're trying to do something programatically, you can check whether or not that query returns 0 or 1, and then apply the `ALTER TABLE` command.